# Swift 2 - Insert device token in the database using PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift

**EDIT:**
I'm developing an iOS application, which uses a webview, that has push notification and I'm trying to pass the device token to a php file (sampleIndex.php) for database registration.

My attempt on posting the device token isn't working. Here's the code:

**EDIT (2)**: My current code is based from @mat 's answer (same concept, but cleaner)

```
extension NSData {
func hexString() -> String {
    // "Array" of all bytes:
    let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes), count:self.length)
    // Array of hex strings, one for each byte:
    let hexBytes = bytes.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
    // Concatenate all hex strings:
    return (hexBytes).joinWithSeparator("")
  }

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let tk = deviceToken.hexString()
    let postBody = NSString(format: "token=%@", tk)
    let endBody = NSURL(string: "http://samplesite.com/subfolder/subfolder2/sampleIndex.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endBody!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    request.HTTPBody = postBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if data != nil {

            print("data: \(response)")

        } else {

            print("failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

        }

    }//closure

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Why can't I get the value of **tk**? (token device). Am I missing something? Sorry, I'm just new to this.

**EDIT (3)**
Here's the php code (sampleIndex.php) where the **token** is being requested:

```
<?php 
  include_once("includes/myConnect.php");
  $token = $_REQUEST['token'];

if (empty($token)) {
  $sql = "UPDATE sampleDB . sampleTB SET token= '0' WHERE id='8982'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}else{
  $sql = "UPDATE sampleDB . sampleTB SET token= '1' WHERE id='8982'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}

?>
```

(token sets to value " 0 " which proves that the device token fails to be passed on sampleIndex.php)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? how will you use the token you upload? what does the log output say? have you used charles proxy to see what is sent?

Comment: sorry for the broadness. the logs while running the app outputs the correct device token, but when it comes to passing it to the php file, it somehow can't receive / get it. *Charles proxy* is new to me, sorry if I don't have any knowledge of it yet

Comment: @Scar check your console. Do you get the following message "failed: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."?

Comment: @mattia None, it doesn't show anything like that or any kind of error / alert. Is my passing method wrong? is there any alternative other than what I'm using right now?

Comment: @Scar are you testing using a real device or the sim?

Comment: @mattia I'm using a real device with the latest OS version. I'm thinking about the server side, is **$_REQUEST** not advisable?

Comment: @Scar have you tried to modify your code as shown below? Can you post your php code?

Comment: @Scar I also use `$_REQUEST` in my php code. nothing wrong with that.

Comment: probably we have to go back to @Wain question. What are you trying to achieve with this code? Usually you save the token to send a push notification to your app but I don't see any code to save in the database.

Comment: you're also just getting the description of the token data and sending it, which would seem to be inappropriate for most usages...

Comment: @mattia well, I deliberately removed the save-to-database part because I can't get the deviceToken. I mean, if I can just at least echo it, then I can return the codes necessary to save it to the database. The problem is, I can't even echo the deviceToken

Comment: can't I echo the deviceToken as a string? just to check if I'm really getting the result

Comment: @Scar you can't do what you are doing with that php code. Every time you reload your page you will only get the an empty alert. you have to write the code to save it in the database and then check if the token is there. The code I posted works. I can modify the question with the code I use to add to my database.

Comment: @mat sorry for not replying sooner, something came up. Anyway, I tried everything you said (triple checked certificates, created a new project, registered in the database), the result is still an empty value in the database. There's something wrong with _my_ posting method and I don't know what. Is it because my app is using webview? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you don't get the following error "**failed: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection**" if you do, add this to your plist:
[image]

The following code works for me. I have just changed the postBody and URL to answer your question but doing that I am able to save the token to my database.

```
extension NSData {
func hexString() -> String {
    // "Array" of all bytes:
    let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes), count:self.length)
    // Array of hex strings, one for each byte:
    let hexBytes = bytes.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
    // Concatenate all hex strings:
    return (hexBytes).joinWithSeparator("")
  }

}


@UIApplicationMain


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    //request notification
    let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound];
    let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
    //register for remote notification - push notification
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications();

    return true
}

fun application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
 let userId = "12345" // not sure you have a userId at this point but you can remove that line and also remove it from postBody
 let tk = deviceToken.hexString()
 let postBody = NSString(format: "user=%@&token=%@", userId, tk)
 let endBody = NSURL(string: "http://www.sampleurl.com/sampleIndex.php")
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endBody!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
 request.HTTPBody = postBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                                                    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

         if data != nil {

          print("data: \(response)")

           } else {

           print("failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

           }

       }//closure

       dataTask.resume()
}
```

To insert the token in the database I strongly suggest you to use prepare statement. I use OOP Php so I have a class Database that handle all the connections but I simplified the code:

**sampleIndex.php**

```
<?php 

$userid = $_REQUEST['user'];
$token = $_REQUEST['token'];

    if (empty($userid) || empty($token)) {
    return;
}else{

    saveTokenToDatabase($userid, $token);
}


function saveTokenToDatabase($user, $token){

    $username = 'youDatabaseUsername';
    $password =  'yourPassword';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', $username, $password);

// first verify if the token is already in the database 
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT token 
        FROM user_tokens 
        WHERE user_id = ? 
          AND token = ? LIMIT 1");

$sth->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$tokenExists = ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;

//if token is not already there 
if(!$tokenExists){

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user_tokens (user_id, token, datecreated)  VALUES(?,?,'".$now."')");
$query->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(2, $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$query->execute();

// determine if token already exists
}
    //close the connection 
    $dbh = null;
}
```

Comment: I've already modified my code to use yours but still no good. Here's my php code

`<?
    $devToken = $_REQUEST['token'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$devToken');</script>";
    ?>
`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just tried adding it to the database, still doesn't work. Here's the code I used: `/* GET DEVICE TOKEN */
 
 $tk = $_REQUEST['token'];
 include_once("includes/dbi_connect.php");
 $sql = "UPDATE tbs_main . tbl_contacts SET token = '$tk' WHERE contact_name='Brian Altman'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: @Scar please see updated answer. I tested and it works. PLEASE don't post code in your comments but your should rather edit your question. `content_name= Brian Altman` is not a good way to design your database. Use name and last name and find your user searching by userId I think it's a better way.

Comment: It's now working. All I did was to add **www.** at

`let endBody = NSURL(string: "http://sampleurl.com/sampleIndex.php")`. Anyway, thank you so much sir for your time and effort

Comment: The code is working. There must be something else. Are you sure you don't get any error in the console?

Comment: It's working now, as I said in my previous comment, all I did was to add **www.** at the beginning of the endBody. Thank you sir for helping me and fixing / cleaning my code

Comment: @Scar I am glad it's working now. you can accept it if you think it helped. cheers